# Initialization of string variables within class perimeters

Tags: java, string, class, inheritance

So, I'm working on a application that counts tickets using inheritance and class perimeters.
This is my code for the class that is challenging.

```
    // For formatting currency
    DecimalFormat currencyF = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    // parameter constructor
    public DiscountTicket(int days, String s) {
        super(days);
        {
            super.daysInAdvance = days;
            getPrice();
        }
    }

    // override getPrice()
    public double getPrice() {
        if (super.daysInAdvance >= 10) {
            super.price = 15;
        }
        if (super.daysInAdvance < 10 && super.daysInAdvance >= 1) {
            super.price = 20;
        }
        return price;

    }

    public String toString() {
    //return "Ticket number: " + number + ", Price: $" + currencyF.format(price) + String s);   
    }
}
```

I need help forming a toString that can execute this class:

```
public class TicketTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int total_sales = 0;

            Ticket[] tickets = {
                    new WebTicket(10),
                    new WebTicket(5),
                    new CounterTicket(),
                    new DiscountTicket(5, "Student"),
                    new DiscountTicket(10, "Senior"),
            };

            for(int i=0; i<tickets.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println( tickets[i] );
            }

            for(int i=0; i<tickets.length; i++) {
                total_sales += tickets[i].getPrice();
            }  

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Total sales: " + total_sales );
    }
```

This toString should help produce the

```
 new DiscountTicket(5, "Student"),
 new DiscountTicket(10, "Senior"),
```

What I really want to know is how to put the "Student" and "Senior" Strings in the DiscountTicket Class using the same variable in the Class's perimeters. It would really be helpful. Maybe I could use the 5 and 10 values to initialize the String values.

My desired output is:

**Ticket: [ serial#: 3 Price: 20 Type: Student]

Ticket: [ serial#: 4 Price: 15 Type: Senior]**

Comment: Hint: look at the `DiscountTicket` constructor. What do you do with `s`?

Comment: tgdavies I've been working on this for hours man help me please.

Comment: Give `DiscountTicket` a `type` field and assign `s` to it in the constructor. Then you can use it in your `toString` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a `StringBuilder` and a `Formatter` for this task.

Consider the following.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(string);
    formatter.format("Ticket: [ serial#: %d ", number);
    formatter.format("Price: %.0f ", price);
    formatter.format("Type: %s]", s);
    formatter.flush();
    return string.toString();
}
```

Output, given the desired output you provided.

```
Ticket: [ serial#: 3 Price: 20 Type: Student]
Ticket: [ serial#: 4 Price: 15 Type: Senior]
```